# jquery formating output on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, web

i have this piece of code so when i click button some json array loads using jquery somthing like this

```
$("#clickmetoload").click(function()
  {
    $('#id').append("<span class=\"id\">"+received.id+"<span  class=\"name\">"+received.name+"</span></span>");
  });
```

but then my outout is all wrong it outputs like this

```
1 2 3 admin user1 user2
```

but i want it to output like this

```
1 admin 
2 user1
4 user2
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing span tag for a start `$('#id').append("<span class=\"id\">"+received.id+"</span><span  class=\"name\">"+received.name+"</span>");`

Comment: it really does out put `1 admin 2 user1 3 user2`

Comment: @kinggs let me update my code

Comment: `<span>` are inline elements so each click will not automagically create a new line. Have you considered wrapping the output in a block-level element, so that each time it gets appended it will end up on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing a `span` closing tag with is the cause to that display
and if you want a line break you should add `<br>` at the end of the line

Here's an example

```js
received = {}
received.id = 0
received.name = "admin"
$("#clickmetoload").click(function() {
  $('#id').append("<span class=\"id\">" + received.id + " </span><span  class=\"name\">" + received.name + "</span><br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickmetoload" value="clickmetoload">clickmetoload</button>
<p id="id"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine in general. You just need some `css` to display it in multi-line. Just use `display: block;` on your outer `span`! ;)

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'admin'},
  {id: 2, name: 'user1'},
  {id: 4, name: 'user2'}
];

$("#clickmetoload").click(function() {
    data.forEach(function(received) {
        $('#id').append("<span class=\"id\">"+received.id+" <span class=\"name\">"+received.name+"</span></span>");
    });
});
```

```css
span.id {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickmetoload">click me to load</button>
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: kinda what i am looking for but it is still the same please note that when data is loaded in to the varible the whole data isnt loaded 
its like when a user connects then the data array will be filled other wise it wouldnt be filled

Comment: I can't follow you. What?! Please update your question with more details and a better example. @za1782852

Comment: will try to do so